# AJAX $_POST is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I want to pass a value between javascript file and php file when I click a button. But when I click the button, I dont see the echo, does anyone see the problem? Here are 2 snippets of my code:

test.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/functions/js/test.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick=" myAjax();">Test</button>

<?php


if($_POST['action'] == 'go') 
    {
    echo "worked";
    }
?>
```

and test.js

```
function myAjax() {


  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:'go'},
       success:function() {

       }

  });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you don't understand how it works. Javascript is client-side, PHP is server-side.

Comment: You know that you don't output anything?

Comment: Your php echo is returning "worked" to the ajax method. Retrieve the echo whithin ajax success. Success:function(response){

Comment: Study some basic ajax tutorials. Code shown doesn't really make much sense

Comment: Success:function(response){ alert(response);}. Javascript is client side, php server side. Also , it is good practice to always have your php code in a seperate file. Use ajax to query this file, get the processed answer using echo to ajax, and append your html or use the response for you javascript. There are 3 main codes, html (to be appended), javascript for user management and controls, php for processing. Try to keep those 3 well separated and dont mix them.

Comment: _To know, is to know that you know nothing. That is the meaning of true knowledge._ - **Socrates**

Comment: Socrates is right. I see to many times html, javascript and php mixed. This is a maintenance nightmare and usualy done by noobs. But he will learn !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all you need to include jQuery library

Second, load your path to file test.js

you should use a class and no call the function myAjax().

Use a class in button such as:
Test

Well, in your test.js file use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Test', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data:{action:'go'},
    success:function(data) {
     console.log('worked');
    }
  });
});
```

ot if just only need send one parameter, use this code, it's easier:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Test', function(e){
  var vars = 'go';
  var params='go='+vars;

  location.href = 'test.php'+params;
});
```

then in your php file you can use $_POSt or $_REQUEST to get vars

```
<?php
  if($_POST['action'] == 'go') 
  {
   echo "worked";
  }
?>
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you receive the response, but don't output it.

Use `console.log` to output to the console:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:'go'},
       success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
       }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get worked inside of success function

```
function myAjax() {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'test.php',
       data:{action:'go'},
       success:function(data) {
           alert(data);//or console.log(data);
       }
  });
}
```